# How do I edit LXC/LXD's raw.lxc config key?

Tags: lxc

I corrupted my raw.lxc key trying to setup lcd/lxc on ubuntu server(15.10 Wiley) by writing some junk to it. Image related lxc commands now return:

'error: problem applying raw.lxc, perhaps there is a syntax error?'

How do I reset/edit this key/file?

Comment: I think there is no way to fix this in the current version of LXC without a complete OS reinstall.

Comment: Why complete OS reinstall? just purge and reinstall lxc... I think that would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, you can probably fix it by simply doing this:

`lxc config unset $CONTAINER_NAME raw.lxc`

No need to re-install. It's extremely rare to need a reinstall with Linux due to most configuration errors, anyway.